# jQuery TableSorter working only on ID (numeric field), not on other fields like text , date etc

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, tablesorter

In my web application I have maintain table for the user records. Records are added and deleted on client send and than user clicks on save button to save all the manipulations done on the server.

I have applied table sorter for the sorting functionality on the table. But surprisingly sorted functionality is working fine for only ID field ie the first field of table, but for all other fields, it is giving error (error trace from chrome)

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
multisortjquery.tablesorter.js:600
$.extend.tablesorter.construct.each.$headers.click.mousedown.onselectstart
```

Here is the table structure.

```
<table id="contentTable" class="tablesorter">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th> ID </th>
                                <th> Name </th>
                                <th> Birth Date </th>
                                <th> City </th>
                                <th id="actionheader"> Action</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

In this I add data dynamically. **In this situation sorting is working fine for only first field ie ID field**

This is how I initialized the tableSorting.

```
  function initializeTableSorting() {
        $("#contentTable").tablesorter({
            sortList : [[0, 0]],
            headers : {
                0 : {
                    sorter : "integer"
                },
                1 : {
                    sorter : "text"
                },
                2 : {
                    sorter : false
                },
                3 : {
                    sorter : "text"
                },
                4 : {
                    sorter : false
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

How can I make this work for all fields, even *also for date field if I remove the false option from the initialization* ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't duplicate the reported error, but if I follow the programming logic...

The error you are describing occurs on this line of code:

```
var s = (table.config.parsers[c].type == "text") ...
```

Which means that `parsers[c]` doesn't exist. The variable `c` is just the column index.

So, if I had to guess, I'd say there is a custom parser involved but it doesn't have a type attribute defined.

```
// default text parser
ts.addParser({
    id: "text",
    is: function (s) {
        return true;
    },
    format: function (s) {
        return $.trim(s.toLocaleLowerCase());
    },
    type: "text"
});
```

Or, it could be a problem with the definition of the `sortList`. Make sure the correct number of square brackets are around the variables:

```
var sorting = [[0, 0]];
$("#contentTable").trigger("sorton", [sorting]);
```

or in compressed form:

```
// more than one column -> [[ [0,0], [1,0] ]]
$("#contentTable").trigger("sorton", [[[0, 0]]]);
```

Try out [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/AqXEA/1/)

Answer (score 6):

Had 'exactly' the same problem and not knowing how to work around it, took sometime, but finally figured that I was providing the tableSorter with an empty row in the data (followed by valid rows). So although I could see valid data in HTML, but in the source I missed out an empty preceeding row... which was probably screwing up the TableSorter JS.

**Removed the beginning empty row**  (after the thead, but before any other data) and this problem was resolved.

Comment: The same thing happened to me, except I just had invalid html in my table - apparently a `tr` shouldn't go in another `tr` ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a weird problem, the [example](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-ajax.html) does not seem to work at all (in Chrome on a Mac). Also, I [recreated your situation](http://jsfiddle.net/AqXEA/), and again, incorrect sorting. Although, I did not get the error you described.

I had this problem with TableSorter before and could not identify the problem back then. If I recall correctly, it had something to do with caching performed by the plugin.

Comment: at my end example is working fine... and also if I apply library on the static table everything works fine but I am adding data dynamically then It creates problem.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me just now.  It would sort the pure numeric fields, but wouldn't do anything via text.  When I pressed those text columns to sort, I returned that "Undefined" error in the Dev Tools Console.

The fix?  Ended up having one of my unrelated functions undefined.